# $HOME/bin in path on Linux Mint 14

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I'd like to amend my user's path in Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon to include $HOME/bin in my user's $PATH.

Warning: simply adding to .profile does not seem to work, even though other commands in .profile are called correctly and even though it works when calling source .profile explicitly.

What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the right file to do the edit into is .bashrc, not .profile. .profile will call .bashrc at its beginning.

Add to .bashrc:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the text in `~/.bashrc` worked for me.  It's just so delightful when the documentation lies to me like right there in the `.profile` file.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying environment variables (like PATH) in and rc script is a very bad
idea.

1: it's executed for all scripts , not just from command line
2: as you get deeper is shells , you'll get more and more prepended paths

.profile or .bash_profile is correct , only done once at login ... seems there is a bug here in Cinnamon

I'm also seeking and answer as to how to set my $PATH in Cinnamon, as the solution (.profile) which has more fine for te past 30 years  is not working here. (nor does .xsessionrc BTW)